# Transparent Background in Lower Third for Export to Different Program

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, transparency

I'm trying to do a lower third in Blender VSE for my husband.  I use blender, but he uses Adobe Premiere.  We're having difficulty exporting and making the background (everything but the lower third) transparent so that we can see the video in the background.  I was able to figure everything else out about animating the lower third by myself via tutorials.  Could someone please give me some direction?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your output to ffmpeg + Quicktime + PNG:

[image]

In the Sequencer View menu select Sequence Render Animation:

[image]